# How to convert transparent layer to solid? (All variants)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, transparency, background, background-removal

I have a transparent layer, like this one (please notice transparency at the center of the image):
[image]

How would you fill the layer with a color like it was done here:

[image]

It is important to fill these semi-transparent areas. Brushes and buckets are not an option.

Answer (score 4):

[image]Just duplicate the layer, use hue/saturation adjustment (Cmd + Alt + U) and drag it to white. done and done. brush the center white if you don't want transparency there.

Answer (score 3):

Use the quick selection tool to select the transparent areas outside the image.

Inverse the selection. Adjust the selection was needed.

Create a new layer.

Fill the selection with a color.

Move the new layer behind the original layer.

Merge the layers.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate the image layer repeatedly until the transparency is gone, then merge the duplicate layers.

Note: this will alter the soft white edge unless you mask that area before duplicating the layers. I would duplicate the image layer once, remove the soft white edge from the duplicate, then duplicate again until the internal translucency becomes opaque.

This way, the colors remain true, you simply build up the slight transparency with each duplication. 60% transparent stacked onto 60% transparent equals an area 100% opaque.